# Data1.cab (1335) error on Windows 7 x64 (in XP 32-Bit VM as well)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, vmware

I built a new PC for my Dad a month ago or so.  Here's the equipment:

```
1 x Intel Core i3-2100 Sandy Bridge 3.1GHz LGA 1155 65W Dual-Core Desktop Processor BX80623I32100
1 x Western Digital Scorpio Blue WD10TPVT 1TB 5200 RPM 2.5" SATA 3.0Gb/s Internal Notebook Hard Drive -Bare Drive 
1 x Crucial 4GB (2 x 2GB) 204-Pin DDR3 SO-DIMM DDR3 1333 (PC3 10600) Laptop Memory Model CT2KIT25664BC1339
1 x ASUS P8H67-I DELUXE (REV 3.0) LGA 1155 Intel H67 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Mini ITX Intel Motherboard
1 x OCZ Vertex 2 OCZSSD2-2VTXE120G 2.5" 120GB SATA II MLC Internal Solid State Drive (SSD)
1 x LITE-ON Black BD-COMBO SATA Model ihes108-29 - OEM
1 x Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit - OEM
```

Anyway, the install of Windows 7 went with no problems.  The problem started when we tried to install applications on the machine.  One example was Quicken 7.  If I tried to install it, i kept getting a 1335 error on data1.cab.  If I installed it on my home PC (Win 7 64 Ultimate), it installs fine.  I thought it was the hard drive, as apps occasionally installed on the DDR.  I replaced the hard drive.  I also tried to install the app in a VMWare Windows XP machine and got the same error.  I thought it could be the Blu-Ray drive, but when i created an ISO on my DVD drive at home and ran it on his PC, i got the same problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Could it be bad RAM?  I'm out of the RMA window on the Parts, but i think i can still get the memory swapped if it is bad.  I guess i could take one stick out at a time, install and see if the problem occurs.

Comment: I'd (also) suggest "take one stick out at a time, install and see if the problem occurs." :)

Comment: Tried changing out the RAM.  Problem still occurs.  Any other ideas?  It's odd that only this computer seems to have the problems with the apps.